# How to connect to local Docker service using `Docker.DotNet` library?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core, docker-api

How can I connect to my local Docker service using [Docker.DotNet](https://github.com/Microsoft/Docker.DotNet) library in **Linux** environment (considering that I am using .Net Core 2.0)?

I think it is somehow related to `/var/run/docker.sock` file, but I could not figure out how to achieve that.

Comment: Did you try `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` as url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been reported, and according to the discussion in [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Docker.DotNet/issues/118), the following should work on linux:

```
DockerClient client = new DockerClientConfiguration(new Uri("unix:///var/run/docker.sock"))
     .CreateClient()
```

Comment: I will try it later, but seems to be the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I created a kind of helpers class which provide the default local api uri depending on the underlying OS:

```cs
public static class Docker
{
    static Docker()
    {
        DefaultLocalApiUri = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) 
            ? new Uri("npipe://./pipe/docker_engine")
            : new Uri("unix:/var/run/docker.sock");
    }

    public static Uri DefaultLocalApiUri { get; }
}
```